# SharePoint 2010 deploying visual web part via a feature

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I've made a VS 2010 project and created 1 wspbuilder solution.

I have 3 features one to deploy columns and one for CT's and one for a web part.

The columns deploy perfectly as do the content types!

When i go to find the feature (in the GUI) for deploying my web part. I can't find it!

I've looked on google to no avail.

THe above code is for my feature. As far as i can see i am getting no errors in the logs.

I have tried ebnabling the feature with powershell but get  The feature is not a farm level feature and is not found in a site level defined by the URL.

```
<Feature  Id="8440ac56-e102-40a4-ac91-1c5249b62fe1"
          Title="******.PMO.TopLevelRollup"
          Description="The description"
          Version="1.0.0.0"
          Hidden="FALSE"
          Scope="Web"
          DefaultResourceFile="core"
          ReceiverAssembly="*******.PMO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=6d3195b961dfcdc1"
          ReceiverClass="********.PMO.EventHandlers.Features.TopLevelRollupReceiver"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml"/>
    <ElementFile Location="********.PMO.TopLevelRollup.webpart" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Maybe i am deploying incorrectly? I use

```
Add-SPSolution
Install-SPSolution -Identity mywspfile.wsp
```

Any help will be muchly appreciated.

Cheers
          Truez

Comment: It seems that the feature is not being deployed. Is the feature in the deployment package? Can you find it in the 14 folder?

Comment: Feature is in the 14 folder which is why it's so confusing!

Comment: You can change the extension of the wsp package to cab and open it in windows explorer or winrar(better). See if the feature is present in the deployment and checkthe manifest.xml of the solution for the feature definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! In VS2010 the Target framework seems to set itself to blank. This gives an error whilst the wsp is being built via wsp builder.

I set the framework to the one I wanted and this seems to work now!

Thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 3):

A web part can be deployed only on site collection level as the access to the web part gallery exists only through site collection root web. You may have to change the feature scope from web to site.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Scope="Web" to Scope="Site" in the feature definition. That should ensure that at least the feature will be available at site level.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have also tried this but no luck! Thanks for the comment :). This i am going to recreate the project.